# How do I implement the Signals (from Django) concept in C#

Tags: c#, django

I'm trying to implement signals from Django (http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/), or its concept in C# to reduce/eliminate coupling/method dependencies.

So far, I'm replicating the code fine, up until the point whereby I realised methods ain't objects in C# as it is in Python. Then I thought of pointers, and then I realised that I can't have pointers to methods. The C# version of it are delegates.

Then I realised delegates have a unique signature to it, so I can't really mix delegated methods (with diff signatures) into a List, or can I?

I did a bit more googling, and found Reactive LINQ, so far, linq looks awesome, but I still don't really get when to use them.

So my question is, how would you implement the Signals concept in C#? Thanks!

Oh did I mention I'm new (1 day old) to C#? I do have a background of various other languages incl Java/C/Python.

Cheers :)

Comment: Are you familiar with the C# concept of "events"? I think this will accomplish exactly what you want, and it's native to the language. :) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(VS.71).aspx

Comment: Agree with Sapph's comment above. Check out building custom classes that descend from EventArgs to transmit differing types of data from sender to receiver(s) as found in sample code here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventargs(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Also think this : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w369ty8x.aspx "How to Publish Events" is a very useful article that shows you very clear examples of the use of generic and non-generic methods of defining Events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are talking about here are typically handled as events in C#, for example;

```
public class SomeType {
    public event EventHandler SomeEvent;
    protected virtual void OnSomeEvent() {
        EventHandler handler = SomeEvent;
        if(handler!=null) handler(this,EventArgs.Empty);
    }
    public void SomethingInteresting() {
        // blah
        OnSomeEvent(); // notify subscribers
        // blap
    }
    // ...
}
```

With subscribers...

```
SomeType obj = new SomeType();
//...
obj.SomeEvent += /* some handler */
//...
```

the handler could be a method, but in your discussion of signatures etc, a common way of re-using existing methods with non-matching signatures is with anonymous methods:

```
obj.SomeEvent += delegate { this.Text = "Done!"; };
```

You *can* have a list of delegates:

```
List<SomeDelegateType> list = new List<SomeDelegateType>();
list.Add(...);
```

but this might be redundant because delegate instances are *multicast* - so you can do this more directly:

```
Action action = null;
action += delegate { Console.WriteLine("Did A");};
action += delegate { Console.WriteLine("Did B");};
action(); // does both A & B
```

Note that more complex delegate usage might involv incoming argument values - for example:

```
int i = 24;
Func<int,int,int> func = (x,y) => (x * i) + y;
int result = func(2, 3); // 51
```

By combining things like anonymous methods (or lambdas, as above) with captured variables, the issue of signatures having to match is rarely an issue - you can just wrap with a lambda to make the signature match (adding extra values or dropping arguments, as required).

Note that with **events** (in particular) the common approach is to keep the signature:

```
void SomeDelegateType(object sender, SomeArgsType args);
```

where `SomeArgsType : EventArgs` - or use `EventHandler<T>` which will do this for you.

Comment: This is a great answer!